# AWS-cdk TypeScript, Need to create two copies of the same environment from my created stack

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, bin, lib, aws-cdk-typescript

I could really do with some guidance, as per the title, I have created a stack with my required AWS services using AWS-cdk v1 (please don't ask about using v2, it has to be v1). Now that I have created my stack, I am trying to create a 'testing/staging' and 'production' of the same environment from using my stack.

Now in lib/ I have created my typescript file with all respective services required and imports of those services followed by:

```
export class TestStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
```

In the bin/I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { TestStack } from '../lib/test-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
```

I have tried the following which throw errors with the deploymentEnvironment, I think I have the wrong setup with code.

In lib:

```
interface MultiStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  deploymentEnvironment: 'Test' | 'Production';
}
```

in bin:

```
new TestDevopsStack(app, 'TestStack', {
     stackName: 'TestStack',
     env: {
         region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
         account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
       },
       deploymentEnvironment: 'test',
     });

 new TestDevopsStack(app, 'ProductionStack', {
     stackName: 'ProductionStack',
     env: {
         region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
         account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
       },
       deploymentEnvironment: 'production',
     });
```

Could anyone shed some light? Please note that I am using aws-cdk v1(1:47.0 in specific)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added an answer. If you're still getting errors when you do that please post your error details and relevant code referenced in stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all that complexity with `MultiStackProps` and deployment environment. CDK does not forbid creating two identical stacks in the same environment, as long as there are no conflicts in names/resource IDs.

Just doing something like this should work:

```
new TestDevopsStack(app, 'TestStack');

new TestDevopsStack(app, 'ProductionStack');
```

If the above fails, it is not because of the problem with stack creation, but rather likely due to conflicting resource names somewhere in your `TestStack` definition. For example, if you hardcode S3 bucket name, then it won't be able to create another copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack accepts a `props` prop with the type `cdk.StackProps` - you need to change that to your `MultiStackProps`, otherwise you will get a type error, since `StackProps` does not have a `deploymentEnvironment` prop.

```
export class TestStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
```

Should be changed to

```
export class TestStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: MultiStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
```

If you run into errors, you'll need to include the error details in the question.

That being said, you might want to re-evaluate the approach of deploying both test and production stacks to the same environment - they should ideally be deployed into separate accounts.